# does AutoMoqCustomization work for abstract classes?

Tags: interface, moq, abstract, xunit.net, autofixture

Please note, I'm somewhat new to TDD, so I will take general advice as well as specific answer.

Neither abstract classes nor interfaces can be instantiated.  Clearly Moq can give me a mocked up instance of the ADataFeed in the second test.  Why does AutoMoqCustomization work for interfaces `IDataFeed` but not for abstract classes `ADataFeed`, instead throwing an InvalidOperationException?

Secondarily, what would be the AutoFixture approach (or TDD generally) be to drive a design that might call for an abstract class with a constructor to require and guarantee certain values, such as a connection string in this case?

```cs
[Theory, AutoMoqData]
public void AllDataFeedsHaveAConectionString(
    IDataFeed sut)
{
    var result = sut.GetConnectionString();
    Assert.Null(result);
}

[Fact]
public void AllDataFeedsRequireAConnectionString()
{
    var expected = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var sut = new Mock<ADataFeed>(expected);
    var result = sut.Object.GetConnectionString();
    Assert.Equal(expected, result);
}

[Theory, AutoMoqData]
public void AllDataFeedsRequireAConnectionString2(
    [Frozen] string expected, 
    ADataFeed sut)
{
    var result = sut.GetConnectionString();
    Assert.Equal(expected, result);
}
```

Comment: `AutoMoqCustomization` can provide abstract base classes as well as interfaces. Is the constructor of `ADataFeed` public? If so, make it protected. It's a design error with a public constructor on an abstract class

Comment: VERY interesting.  Ok, moq handles a public constructor on abstract class... autofixture doesn't.  Neither work with a private constructor and both work when it is protected.  I'll take your word for it that it is a design error... another question for another day. In the interim I'll use protected.

Comment: FTR: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229047(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Did that resolve your issue?

Comment: yes, I think my question is resolved... the second half is probably too expansive and subjective... I just have to get better at TDD.  Right now, my testing isn't helping me from getting bogged down in implementation. -- I don't know how to mark your comments as an answer tho.

Comment: The important thing is that you get answers to your questions :) Regarding the second part of the question, do yourself the favor of not creating abstract classes, and everyting will be much simpler :) "Favor object composition over class inheritance."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstract classes with constructors must be marked protected.  AutoFixture will not program against abstract classes when the constructor is marked public, as this is a design error.